# Boost +12v from ATX PSU to ~13.5-14.5v

Tags: power-supply, batteries, charger, automotive, atx

I understand that what I am doing requires the utmost care and that numerous precautions should be taken in completing a project like this.

**Out of necessity**, I am going to fashion a car battery charger from an ATX PSU. I need to draw ~14v to do this, I'm guessing from the +12v rail.

How can I tell if this will be possible for the PSU I have?

What I know:

- This model uses HA17431PNA shunt regulators, which I have located on the circuit.
- I will need to modify that IC's input circuit to adjust the regulator's voltage.
- This may also require me to adjust the output caps, but given the step-up value it also may not.

What I don't know:

- Precisely how to tackle this -- I have a decent soldering station and resistors, but this would be the first time I worked on something other than a phone/doing rework. I found the spec sheet from Hitachi for the regulator. What other resources should I consult?
- What generates DC from AC in an ATX PSU? A transformer? Is the transformer able to generate this voltage for me without affecting other components?
- How this will affect the current output on the rail.
- Any other unknowns regarding how this modification might impact the performance of the PSU.

Can someone please help me accomplish this task?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: hmm HA17431 seems to be a clone of TL431, (`17` reflected vertically even looks like `TL`)

Comment: A lead-acid battery should not be charged using a fixed voltage.  Automotive battery chargers intended to intelligently charge 12 volt lead-acid batteries should be readily available.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the feedback is taken from the 3.3V output and fed back using a TL431. There might be a second TL431 for the auxiliary power supply.

To change the voltage you would increase the series resistor from the 3.3V to the feedback terminal of the TL431/HA17431. This will increase the positive output voltages (usually the negative ones have fixed regulators).

However if the power supply has overvoltage protection, as many (and *all* good ones) do, then you may trigger that and your power supply will shut down. Without a schematic it is going to be difficult to determine how to deal with that.

Comment: good point about over-voltage.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the voltage output you need to reduce the resistor between the REF and A pins of the HA17431

increasing the 12V will also cause the 5V and 3.3V to increase

Comment: Usually the A pin goes off to some other bit of circuitry- it's not a simple shunt regulator. In small supplies it goes to an optocoupler, in bigger ones (with a second auxiliary supply) to some discretes.

Comment: I would expect the optiocoupler to be above the device connected to K - A and K terminals are labeled as in a zener diode)

Comment: [Here](http://danyk.cz/impulz.gif) is a typical arrangement with an optocoupler. In modern PC supplies there may not be an optocoupler at that position- the control circuitry isn't running at mains potential- so it will be a PNP or something like that.

Comment: connected to `K`